# Getting resources in VFrabric Server to deploy without causing container to reload

Tags: spring, spring-tool-suite

I want resources *.css, *.jsp etc. to deploy to the application when they are saved, however, not cause the entire server to reload (which is what is happening at the moment).

I have checked the "Enable JMX-based reloading" box which looked like it was what I wanted but it has appeared to do nothing (container is still reloading when a resource is saved).

How can I achieve this?  I am using STS as below.

Spring Tool Suite

Version: 3.2.0.RELEASE
Build Id: 201303060821

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you map the application root to a context instead of the root '/' it works!

Comment: This is really annoying since I want to map my application to '/' but also don't want to trigger reload on all changes. Someone know a solution for this?